# django render to xml like html

Tags: python, xml, django, django-templates

I'm trying to render to xml in by `django.shortcut.render_to_response`， but it seems not working. can any only find some solutions to work over this?

here is the code

```
class BaseResponse(object):
    """
    这个类类似于Django的通用视图，response_name是要输出的消息模版
    msg是用户输入消息的一个字典,如果要自定义消息，只要自定义context
    就可以了，消息内容格式由微信官方指定
    """
    template_name = None
    response_type = "application/xhtml+xml"

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.template_context = {'ToUserName': msg['FromUserName'], 'FromUserName': msg['ToUserName'],
                                 'CreateTime': time.time()}

    def get_response(self, context=None):
        self.template_context.update(context)
        res = render_to_response(self.template_name, context=self.template_context,
                                 content_type=self.response_type)
        return self.template_context
```

and some xml

```
<xml>
    <ToUserName><![CDATA[{{ ToUserName }}]]></ToUserName>
    <FromUserName><![CDATA[{{ FromUserName }}]]></FromUserName>
    <CreateTime>{{ CreateTime }}</CreateTime>
    <MsgType><![CDATA[text]]></MsgType>
    <Content><![CDATA[{{ Content }}]]></Content>
</xml>
```

Comment: Why don't you return `res` ?

Comment: sorry，I'm just testing. I found if `render_to_response` is used,then app would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to pass dict of context and return response object. Something like this

```
def get_response(self, context=None):
        self.template_context.update(context)
        return render_to_response(self.template_name, self.template_context,
                                 content_type=self.response_type)
```

Comment: sorry I was just writing code like that to test. The original code is what you just wrote.

Comment: @whatout, can you explain _it doesn't work_? Also, have you set appropriate `template_name`?

Comment: here is the code
`class TextResponse(BaseResponse):
    template_name = '/lib/text_response.xml'
class MusicResponse(BaseResponse):
    template_name = '/lib/music_response.xml'`

Comment: I run it on a remote server, So I can not get any message. But I think it cause by django's ability to render xml